# ToList().ForEach in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am new to Linq.

I want to set two values in `foreach` statement like this

My actual code is this

```
foreach (Employee emp in employees)
{
    foreach(Department dept in emp.Departments)
    {
        dept.SomeProperty = null;
    }
    collection.AddRange(emp.Departments);              
}
```

Little refactoring turns the above into this

```
foreach (Employee emp in employees)
{
    emp.Departments.ToList().ForEach(u => u.SomeProperty = null))
    collection.AddRange(emp.Departments);              
}
```

But I want something like this

```
employees.ToList().Foreach(collection.AddRange(emp.Departments),
emp.Departments.ToList().ForEach(u => u.SomeProperty = null))
```

Comment: NO! Don't convert your collection to a list just to call that method... Use your loops.

Comment: Think about performance too while changing to Linq. Not always LINQ is helpful compared to normal loops.

Comment: Do that and nobody can read your code again. Self obfuscation.

Comment: The original code is perfectly clear and understandable; I see no need to change it. Remember, the purpose of code is not just to communicate to the *compiler* it is to communicate to the future reader of the code; make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you Eric. Had I not been accustomed to READING all comments now I would have missed this valuable recommendation.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ForEach` in that way. Read Lippert's [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach)

If you want to be cruel with yourself (and the world), at least don't create useless `List`

```
employees.All(p => {
    collection.AddRange(p.Departments);
    p.Departments.All(u => { u.SomeProperty = null; return true; } );
    return true;
});
```

Note that the result of the `All` expression is a `bool` value that we are discarding (we are using it only because it "cycles" all the elements)

I'll repeat. You shouldn't use `ForEach` to change objects. LINQ should be used in a "functional" way (you can create new objects but you can't change old objects nor you can create side-effects). And what you are writing is creating so many useless `List` only to gain two lines of code...

Comment: Although what we're suggesting here is to replace the `ToList()` abuse with an `All` abuse. ;)

Comment: @IlianPinzon I thought I was quite clear of this. Do you think I should **bold** it? :-)

Comment: I prefer a blinking marquee that says "DO NOT (AB)USE." :) Newbies may read the example as gospel if they skip the disclaimer text above. :)

Comment: Atleast with removing the ToList it isn't copying the collection in memory just to iterate over it and throw it away. On large-ish collection ToList is deadly.

Answer (score 24):

As xanatos said, this is a misuse of ForEach.

If you are going to use linq to handle this, I would do it like this:

```
var departments = employees.SelectMany(x => x.Departments);
foreach (var item in departments)
{
    item.SomeProperty = null;
}
collection.AddRange(departments);
```

However, the Loop approach is more readable and therefore more maintainable.

Comment: +1 Wow! Beautiful use of `SelectMany` (not that I would use it :-) )

Comment: Though it might be better to add the range after you modify them so it logically makes sense that you're adding modified items to the collection.  The collection may even store copies of the items so this might not work.

Comment: It's probably even better to remove the `AddRange` line which does an unnecessary additional traversal of the sequence. One can do `collection.Add(item)` inside the existing loop with the same result.

Comment: @Jeff I hadn't thought of that, fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

```
employees.ToList().ForEach(
     emp=>
     {
          collection.AddRange(emp.Departments);
          emp.Departments.ToList().ForEach(u=>u.SomeProperty = null);
     });
```

Comment: So adding .ToList() allows Linq .ForEach()... Nice!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
foreach (var dept in employees.SelectMany(e => e.Departments))
{
   dept.SomeProperty = null;
   collection.Add(dept);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
employees.ToList().Foreach(u=> { u.SomeProperty = null; u.OtherProperty = null; });
```

Notice that I used semicolons after each set statement
that is -->

```
u.SomeProperty = null;
u.OtherProperty = null;
```

I hope this will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.ForEach()`

```
Array.ForEach(employees, employee => {
   Array.ForEach(employee.Departments, department => department.SomeProperty = null);
   Collection.AddRange(employee.Departments);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

you want this?

```
    employees.ForEach(emp =>
    {
        collection.AddRange(emp.Departments.Where(dept => { dept.SomeProperty = null; return true; }));
    });
```

Answer (score -4):

Try with this combination of Lambda expressions:

```
employees.ToList().ForEach(emp => 
{
    collection.AddRange(emp.Departments);
    emp.Departments.ToList().ForEach(dept => dept.SomeProperty = null);                    
});
```