# Very easy lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Ciao everyone,
i was finally able to switch from .NET Framework 2.0 to .NET Framework 4.0.

I am trying to get some experience about lambda expression and LINQ.

Is it possible to translate this:

```
for (int cont = 0;cont < args.Length; cont++)
    Console.WriteLine("#" + cont + " " + "<" + args + ">");
```

into a single line lambda expression,or using LINQ, or even some other costruct i am no aware of ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you tryng to do with `"<" + args` part? Args is a string[] array I think, correct?

Comment: I think in this example your code is the best solution to write every item to the console. :) But you can use LINQ to query the args collection if you wanna do something else with the items.

Comment: I think you want `args[cont]` instead of `args` in your second line.

Comment: args[] is the input string[] of a console application. In the log of the application i wantto write something like:

#1 <Input arg 1>
#2 <Input arg 2>
#3 <Input arg 3>
...

I thought there was an easy one line expression sintax for it

Comment: It should be `args[cont]` then, if args is an array.

Comment: like xanatos and Etienne say, don't use LINQ just because its possible and new, a normal `for` or `foreach` will likely have equal or better performance here and more importantly is simple to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ operations shouldn't have side effects or do actions. They should only be used to produce, from a `IEnumerable<T>` another `IEnumerable<T>` (or from a `IQueryable<T>` another `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`) (or if aggregating, like `.Max`, `.All`... a single result)

Read for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx.

(and note that this question is quite asked on SO... Read for example my reply here [ToList().ForEach in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816781/tolist-foreach-in-linq) and see a solution to a similar problem)

Now, if you hate yourself enough, you can do this:

```
strs.Select((p, index) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("#" + index + " " + "<" + p + ">");
    return true;
}).All(p => p);
```

We are using the `.All(p => p)` to "materialize" the `Select` operation. This because `Select` is "lazy" and won't be executed if no one cycles it.

Technically you could even try to obfuscate it a little:

```
strs.Select((p, index) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("#" + index + " " + "<" + p + ">");
    return false;
}).Any(p => p);
```

(`All` checks that all the elements are `true` and stops if one of the is `false`, so it has to cycle all of them (because we always `return true;`). `Any` (as written) checks that at least one of the elements is `true` and then stops (but all of our elements are `false`, becasue we do `return false;` so the `Any` will cycle all the elements)

Now... The advantage of these techniques over using `ToList` is that we aren't "duplicating" an `Array` to a `List<T>` just to use a "wrong" method of `List<T>`. If the `ForEach` method of `List<T>` is "wrong", duplicating an `Array` to a `List` just to use it is doubly-wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There's something you must understand first. LINQ is a *functional* style API. It's main purpose is to provide an easy and concise way to manipulate sequences.

Your code *could* be written using LINQ, but it's not desirable: writing stuff to a stream (such as a console) is best done in imperative style, and your request smacks of golden hammer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would want this but:

```
   args.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("#{0} <{1}>",
        args.ToList().IndexOf(i),
        i));
```

I suppose you did want to output the item itself and not the whole list on every line.

And I've made the construction of the output somewhat nicer.

IMO: Your original code is faster and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, i think you are right. Since those are my first step into lamba i just thought that there was a better solution. However VS2010 intellisense show the method ".ToList<>" at first. Shouldn't it shows two separate methods ".ToList<>" and ".ToList()" ?

Comment: The method is actually `.ToList<string>()`, but the compiler can resolve the `<string>` part, so you can leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

Converting it to a lambda expression is trivial, and useless.

```
Action doLoop = ()=>{for (int cont = 0;cont < args.Length; cont++)
    Console.WriteLine("#" + cont + " " + "<" + args + ">");}
```

But if you want to replace the loop with linq, that's possible but a bad idea. Linq is designed for side effectless code, `Console.WriteLine` is a side effect.

If you want to use linq, but still keep the `Console.WriteLine` call you could write:

```
foreach(string s in Enumerable.Range(0,args.Length).Select("#" + cont + " " + "<" + args + ">"))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

It would be possible to abuse `Select` to entirely eliminate the loop, but that's too ugly to post here.

Many people have defined a `ForEach` extension method with which the code becomes:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,args.Count).ForEach(()=>Console.WriteLine("#" + cont + " " + "<" + args + ">"));
```

But I'm not fond of this style.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this links will help you to understand and learn Lambdas and Linq.

[MSDN Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

[101 LINQ Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you've asked for:

```
    args
        .Select((x, n) => String.Format("#{0} <{1}>", n, args))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

It produces the same as your code:

```
#0 <System.String[]>
#1 <System.String[]>
#2 <System.String[]>
```

I'm guessing you wanted something more like this:

```
var args = new [] { "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", };

args
    .Select((x, n) => String.Format("#{0} <{1}>", n, x))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Which produces:

```
#0 <Apple>
#1 <Banana>
#2 <Cherry>
```

Comment: Well, code looks more complicated than the original to be honest. Wondering if it's translated into the same IL code

Comment: Ah well, it's one line and it's LINQ. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming something like this:

```
string[] args = new string[] { "a", "pippo", "c" };
```

you can try this:

```
args.ToList().ForEach(
    p => Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("# {0} <{1}>", p, args.Length)));
```

Answer (score -1):

your args must be an array:

```
Array.ForEach(args, s => { Console.WriteLine("#" + Array.IndexOf(args, s) + " " + "<" + args + ">"); });
```

Comment: Not equivalent with the original code(doesn't work with duplicate items) and slower ( just `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`)