# How to use a foreach loop with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I'm having a few problems using a foreach loop with LINQ, this is the code I have so far what I'm trying to do is get a list of customers associated with a particular booking, any help would be appreciated =]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;   


namespace BookingCustomers
{
    public partial class BookingGuests : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private HotelConferenceEntities datacontext = new HotelConferenceEntities();



        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {

                    int id = int.Parse(BookID.Text.ToString());
                    tblBooking booking = datacontext.tblBookings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookingID == id);

                    tblVenue venue = datacontext.tblVenues.SingleOrDefault(x => x.VenueID == booking.Venue);


                    List<tblCustomer> customers = new List<tblCustomer>();
                    List<tblBookingGuest> guests = booking.tblBookingGuests.ToList();



                    foreach (list<tblBookingGuest> in tblBookingGuest)
                    {



                    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the Related Thread in this Forum 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816781/tolist-foreach-in-linq

Comment: `having a few problems`. okay, let me turn the telepathist mode on and guess which

Comment: The question is totally unclear. Are you trying to retrieve all customers from guests? How can you retrieve from a selected guests item the customers? Has it functions/properties?

Comment: _get a list of customers associated with a particular booking_ This is not about how to use `foreach`! This is about how to query. For that we need to see your class model.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the loop variable declaration, and the declared type was wrong - oh, and you were using the wrong sequence. I think this is what you want:

```
foreach (var guest in booking.tblBookingGuests)
{
    // Do something with guest
}
```

Note that your line of code

```
List<tblBookingGuest> guests = booking.tblBookingGuests.ToList();
```

is superfluous. It will make a copy of the entire sequence of booking guests.

You should just use `booking.tblBookingGuests` directly in the `foreach` *unless* you are going to modify the list itself rather than the items in it. (If you do that, it won't change the original, of course.)

Comment: I just tried this Matthew and I get an error from Visual Studio that says BookingCustomers.tblBookingGuest is a type but is used like a 'variable

Comment: @ReeceCottam I think I might have ninja-edited my reply. Does it work now?

Comment: Superfluous for some, more readable and maintainable for others, as for speed, the compilers optimizer will most likely produce identical code for either.

Comment: @PaulZahra You don't seem to be understanding what I'm saying. The `.ToList()` will be making an entire copy of the sequence, and *that* is what is superfluous. Can't you see the `ToList()` at the end there? You don't need to make an entire copy of a sequence in a `List<>` before you enumerate over it!

Comment: of course... my bad... bit busy buying a house today... mind elsewhere... was thinking only of the foreach statement to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Surely what you want is:

```
foreach (tblBookingGuest guest in guests)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: with this answer Paul I'm getting a different error, stating that type and identifier are both required for a foreach statement

Comment: Oh nevermind! i didn't assign a name to tblbookingGuest I've got it sorted now =D thankyou very much!

Comment: Perhaps a null / empty list test wouldn't go amiss, encase there aren't any bookings. P.S. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to access to all the tblBookingGuest in the booking variable.

```
foreach (tblBookingGuest guest in guests)
{
 //something
}
```

Please remember that you cannot directly modify a member of the guests list into the foreach loop.

Hope it could help.

Answer (score 1):

How about pure linq :

```
    booking.tblBookingGuests.ToList().ForEach(a =>
    {
        // Do your stuff
    });
```