# Is there a LINQ way of doing something like a foreach and then calling a function?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
foreach (var objectiveDetail in add)
{
    _uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add(objectiveDetail);
}
```

Is there a way I could do this in LINQ.

Comment: Is there any particular reason or it's just because "I can"? To me it's perfectly valid and even more readable your current approach...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or just:

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.AddRange(add);
```

Comment: +1 My personal favorite.. Assuming _uow.ObjectiveDetails is a type that supports `AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`.

Comment: If not.. LINQ's `Concat` is the same.

Comment: If I could +2 this I would.. The add range uses the `Array.Copy` and 'Array.CopyTo' methods which do not enumerate the set if the added collection implements `ICollection<T>`. Although marginal will execute quicker and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
add.Foreach(o => _uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add(o));
```

Try the above

Here is another answer/question [ToList().ForEach in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816781/tolist-foreach-in-linq)

Comment: I think I recommend using your original approach though. It's more readable IMO

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
add.ForEach( (objectiveDetail) => _uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add(objectiveDetail));
```

By the way this is not `LINQ.`This is just a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of generic `List<T>` class.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer as I believe it was the first correct answer.

Comment: This isn't strictly correct. Only `List<T>` natively supports this method. You need to include a reference to the Interactive Framework (by the Reactive Framework guys) to get this on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I mention it just now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a foreach if `add` is a `List<T>` by calling the method `ForEach(Action<T> action)`

Such as.

`add.ForEach(item => _uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add(item));`