# Associate variable to a list

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if this is easy possible in C#. But I would like to get to know how this could be done easily.

```
public partial class Form1
{
  // I left out the unimportant code for this example
  private myControl cLeft,cTop,cBottom,cRight;
  private List<myControl>mControls;
  public Form1()
  {
  InitializeComponents();
  //this list should contain the fields cLeft,cTop,cBottom,cRight...
  mControls=new List<myControl>(){cLeft,cTop,cBottom,cRight};
  /* now I want that cLeft and so on get assigned...
  of course, this doesn't work because the list refers to the values of
   cLeft ... which are null. So I would need to store a reference to those fields to get this work.*/
  mControls.ForEach(x=>x=new myControl(this));
  }

}
```

I'm sure it could be done through reflection, but I assume that there should be a way to do this easily in C# or isn't it possible?

Comment: This isn't possible, even with reflection. You'd have to do some trickery with `unsafe` to achieve that. It's also a *really really* bad idea to do this, you should rethink what you're trying to achieve. Variables being changed behind your back through code which appears to have nothing to do with the variables is a recipe for an undebuggable codebase.

Comment: This looks similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816781/tolist-foreach-in-linq

Comment: @GrantWinney myControl doesn't exist in the designer. This question is not asking about creating controls, it is asking about refering to fields

Comment: @singsuyash not similar. I want to set the variables cLeft and so on through iterating over a list of "references" to them

Comment: note that i flagged your question as dupe because the other guy is actually trying what you want to achieve. `params with ref`. good idea but it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple loop, there is no need to use LINQ. You just need a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < mControls.Count ; i++) {
    mControl[i] = new myControl(this);
}
```

**But**, there is no need to write `cLeft`, `cTop` etc. You can just refer to them using the indexer: `mControls[0]`, `mControl[1]` etc.

And remember, the `foreach` loop or the `ForEach` extension method doesn't work. This is because you are changing the *reference* of the variable. That is just another confusing (for beginners) feature of reference types!

Consider this method

```
public void ChangeReference (string s) {
    s = "Hello";
}
```

And you call this method:

```
String s = "xxx";
ChangeReference (s);
```

Will `s` be "Hello" after the call? No. In the method, you are changing the location of the string in memory, but the argument is still in the same place!

Comment: I think his main goal is to quickly instantiate the `cLeft`, `cTop`, etc.. variables in a single statement - rather than creating x number of controls. While your solution is most likely the better approach, it's answering a slightly different question

Comment: @Rob I have never seen someone asks for a single statement to instantiate a lot of objects! And OP is not likely to ask that. Technically, a `foreach` loop is a statement block which is counted as a "statement".

Comment: Just because no one's asked it before, doesn't mean this question isn't asking it :). From the original post: `now I want that cLeft and so on get assigned...` I'm not saying it's a good idea (in fact I left a comment saying the opposite on the question) - but that appears to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Sweeper , recently I tried asking what rob mentioned. But I had no clue how to describe this properly